# How to flip bars in d3

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, svg

I'm having trouble flipping my bars. It seems like they're 'growing" but under the x axis. I know that in SVG, the (0,0) coordinates are at the top left and I managed to bring them to the bottom of my SVG but how do I change the direction of my bars from under the x-axis to over the axis?

```
var formatYear = d3.timeFormat("%Y");

var svg = d3.select("svg"); // calling svg 
const width = +svg.attr('width'); // width of svg container
const height = +svg.attr('height'); // height of svg container

var padding = 30
// create d3 data join

// load csv file 
d3.csv("q3.csv").then(data => {
data.forEach(d => {
  d.year = d.year; // need to format year
  d.running_total = +d.running_total // format to number
});
render(data);
});


const render = data => {
const yValue = d => d.running_total;
const xValue = d => d.year;
const margin = {
  top: 20,
  right: 20,
  bottom: 20,
  left: 20
};

const xScale = d3.scaleBand()
  .domain([0, data.map(xValue)])
  .range([0, width])
// Line 38
const yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, d3.max(data, yValue)])
  .range([0, height])
console.log(yScale.domain())


//      const g = svg.append('g')
//          .attr('transform','translate(${margin.left},${margin.top})'
// );

svg.selectAll('rect').data(data)
  .enter().append('rect') // Line 47
  .attr('x', d => yValue(d))
  .attr('y', height) // Line 48
  .attr('height', d => yValue(d)) // Line 49
  .attr('width', 5);


};
```

How it looks after Andrew's suggestion:
[image]

Comment: Can you post an example online?

Comment: of how I want it to look like or how it looks like right now?

Comment: obviously how it looks now since you aren't able to get it to flip...

Comment: You want the bottom of the bars to be equal to `height`, right now you are setting the *top* of the bars to this value: `.attr('y', height)`. Instead subtract the bar's length from `height` to get the top value (/the y attribute) of the bar: `.attr('y', function(d) { return height-yValue(d))`.

Comment: @AndrewReid when I do that, it seems like my bars are truncated and  the position of each bar moves according to the value I gave the x coordinate. I've updated the post to show how it looks like after the changes.

Comment: Actually...I was able to get it to work! thanks! now I just have to figure out the spacing